# Removing block of code is the string is found in entire block using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file `DJ.bat` file. I am reading the content of file using powershell.

```
DJENGINE -l "Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_2554_20220323065246.tf.err" -sc "File=Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_2554_20220323065246.dat" -tc "Server=ABC.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com;Database=ABCTMS_FC;Table=dbo.FC_Load" "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Data\Retail\Actian11\MapDesigner\fc.tf.xml"
DJENGINE -l "Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_5168_20220323074029.tf.err" -sc "File=Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_5168_20220323074029.dat" -tc "Server=ABC.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com;Database=ABCTMS_FC;Table=dbo.FC_Load" "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Data\Retail\Actian11\MapDesigner\fc.tf.xml"
DJENGINE -l "Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_13272_20220323070111.tf.err" -sc "File=Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_13272_20220323070111.dat" -tc "Server=ABC.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com;Database=ABCTMS_FC;Table=dbo.FC_Load" "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Data\Retail\Actian11\MapDesigner\fc.tf.xml"
```

I have thousand of -`DJENGINE` lines of statement being printed. I have just mentioned three here

I have an array `$data` which has thousands of data. I just mentioned two here:

```
TMSfuture_cost_2554_20220323065246.dat
TMSfuture_cost_5168_20220323074029.dat
```

I want result that the `content of array` are compared within the `content of file being read`. If the ,content of array **matches** then I need to delete block of code from :

```
   " DJEngine.... to .... tf.xml"
```

Since these `two arrays` matches with `file content`, My expected output is:

```
DJENGINE -l "Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_13272_20220323070111.tf.err" -sc "File=Y:\st\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\TMSfuture_cost_13272_20220323070111.dat" -tc "Server=ABC.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com;Database=ABCTMS_FC;Table=dbo.FC_Load" "\\ccaintranet.com\dfs-dc-01\Data\Retail\Actian11\MapDesigner\fc.tf.xml"
```

I tried using:

```
$pathOFDj='Y:\St\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\DJ.bat'
foreach($d in $data){
  foreach($line in Get-Content $pathOFDj) {
    if($line -contains $d){

    }
    else{
      $newLine+=$line
    }
  }
}

echo $newLine
```

The block which I mentioned is not being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current script has 3 major problems:

- Wrong comparison operator - `-contains` is for testing *collection containment*, not substrings - you'd want something like `-like` or `-match` for string comparisons instead
- Repeated positives - even if one string from `$data` is found in a specific line, the line will still be copied/included on the next iteration of the outer loop because it won't contain the remaining `$data` substrings
- Subquadratic time complexity - testing every single item in `$data` against every single line in the file gives your script a bounding time complexity of `O(N*M)` where `N` is the number of `$data` items and `M` is the number of lines in the file. This means your code is going to get significantly slower when you increase the input size. By structuring your code differently this can be improved somewhat, and by structuring you *data* differently this can be improved *massively*

Instead of attempting to solve these problems point-by-point, I'm gonna show you how to prepare the `$data` array and parse the input file for better performance (and correctness of course).

This will consist of two steps:

- Organize the `$data` items into a data structure that allows for *constant-time lookups* - something that can tell us, as quickly as possible, whether a specific string is part of the collection or not.
- Parse the relevant file name out of each line in the file, use the extracted file name to test if the collection from the previous set contains it, and use that to filter out the relevant line

```
$pathOFDj='Y:\St\Retail\FTP\2022-03-23\DJ.bat'

# Read file names into array
$data = Get-Content path\to\listOfFileNames.txt

# Create a hashset - this will provide super-fast lookups
$fileNameSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([System.StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
$data |ForEach-Object { [void]$fileNameSet.Add($_) }

# Now we can start parsing and filtering the file
Get-Content $pathOFDj |Where-Object {
  # attempt to extract file name, then use the extracted file name to test if it's one of the relevant file names
  -not($_ -match '-sc "File=[^"]+?\\([^\\"]+)"' -and $fileNameSet.Contains($Matches[1]))
} |Set-Content path\to\modified_dj.bat
```

The statement `-not($_ -match '-sc "File=[^"]+\\([^\\"]+)"' -and $fileNameSet.Contains($Matches[1]))` will only evaluate to `$false` if a filename was successfully extracted and found to be contained in the hashset - otherwise, it'll evaluate to `$true`, and `Where-Object` will let the line filter through as expected.

Comment: I dont see $data  being used. where is it being computed?

Comment: @DikshitKarki Correct, I forgot to include the line that populates the set, I've just updated the answer :)

Comment: i checked into the modified_bat file and still see the filename which was meant to be deleted

Comment: i have considered $data as arraylist in my code. I have added all the filename using $data.add($l). I think regex is not matching. The files are still showing in modified_dj file

Comment: @DikshitKarki Did you try the updated version (with the `$data |ForEach-Object { ... }` statement)? If I use the two file names you've posted as the contents of `$data` it works and only spits out the last line of the file

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference. Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71600620/edit) with realistic examples (both file names and bat file contents)

Comment: hi @mathias , if we can chat then we can look into it. Please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243286/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-dikshit-karki).